# KVO method firing twice on NSManagedObject property

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, key-value-observing

As the title says, I'm observing an NSManagedObject property with KVO. The method `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)` is firing twice : The first time when assigning  a new value to the property, and the second time when I'm saving the context in CD. I'm doing that immediately after setting the property value. I'm having another problems in the code because of that, my question is why is this happening, and what would be the right way to do it (set the property, saving the context and firing the method once). Maybe I shouldn't save the context immediately after?

Comment: A guess: since the object is 'dirtied' when you update its value, upon saving, likely all the properties are scrubbed by saving the changes to the store and then refreshing all the properties on your instance with the content from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my above comment (intuition) is actually correct. It seems to be undocumented, but observed on all platforms that mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification (i.e. when your MOC saves) triggers a refresh on all properties. 
cf: [KVO notifications after mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577929/kvo-notifications-after-mergechangesfromcontextdidsavenotification)

a suggestion for how to handle the behavior: kvo code, in general, should be idempotent and fast, precisely because it could get called often, i.e. when the keypath is set.

Comment: I see now, that's correct. Thank you for your help! I will mark this as the correct answer. I have moved the saving to other part of the code on where I already removed the object as observer of the property so it will fire one time!